# Using Kubuntu, how can I setup a keyboard shortcut to change the current language

Tags: kde, kubuntu, input-languages

I am using Kubuntu and have successful configured my system to support two languages.
Using the KDE keyboard tool I'm able to switch between them by clicking on the little flag icon.

How do I setup a keyboard shortcut? I have "enable xkb checked" and I selected <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "System Settings/Mouse and keyboard/Global hotkeys", select the "Keyboard layout switcher" (or whatever it is called) application, and set the hotkey for what you want it to be. The default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, but I prefer <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> instead.

Note: I am using a language other than English so the exact phrases may differ.

Comment: this works! strange thing is that I can't switch back to English. I guess this is because the K is no longer a K. I changed it to use the menu button. Thanks

Comment: @DanJ in windows default is alt+shift. Here i posted bug that it cant be put on working for any language layout without moving k https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemsettings/+bug/1882358

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found 'Global hotkeys' yet...
There is (a.o.)
System Settings->General->Personal->Regional->Keyboard Layout

but I haven't found anything about hotkeys (BTW I'm using KDE 3.5.10)

> strange thing is that I can't switch back to English. I guess > this is because the K is no longer a K.

That's one of the advantages of Mac OS X (IMHO). Shortcuts are bound with a particular key, not with whatever code that key generates.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer for 2021 using Kubuntu 20.04

Open `System Settings`, on the left find `Input Devices` and open it, select `Keyboard`, then click on `Advanced`. Scroll down a little until you see `Switching to another layout`. Double-click on it and select one of the provided shortcuts.